# Stack Overflow during SWAP

Tags: overflow, swap

How can we take care of the overflow happening during swapping of two variables without using a third variable. I believe the XOR solution can be used only for integers. what about other variable types?

Comment: other types like ..? what language, btw?

Comment: Just a hunch... this wouldn't be C++ with the swap happening in a copy-constructor, would it?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an answer but it doesn't fit in a comment.

Under what circumstances would you be running so close to the edge of your available stack storage that the additional use of a temporary variable for the swap is going to cause you difficulties?

I could see some embedded scenarios, but I'm hard pressed to imagine a scenario where you'd be so tight on stack space that this would matter (where you're not writing code in assembly language).

Answer (score 2):

XOR will work for anything you can get your XOR operator to process; it's a property of binary data, not of binary data used to represent integers.

Comment: Only if the XOR operator is actually performing an XOR operation, not if it's been overloaded to do something weird (in a language which allows operator overloading, that is).

Comment: Ugh; yeah, that's true, and worth mentioning.  Thanks.

Comment: So cast the data back to integer or char array and do the xor on the elements of that.

Answer (score 2):

By not doing it at all.  The XOR swap algorithm is cool hack.  It [shouldn't be used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice) in production code.

Answer (score 0):

The XOR solution works with any type that can be bitwise copied, not just integers. However, do not XOR a variable with itself: i.e.

```
int x = 10;
int *p1 = &x;
int *p2 = p1;

*p1 = *p1 ^ *p2;
*p2 = *p1 ^ *p2;
*p1 = *p1 ^ *p2;

/* now x == 0 :( */
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with [XCHG](http://www.intel.com/software/products/documentation/vlin/mergedprojects/analyzer_ec/mergedprojects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct64_hh/6400380.htm)?  No stack needed, no overflow(carry flag)? set either :).

Comment: Read the link in this answer and then follow footnote 2 and read that. In short - it messes up CPU cache, thus slowing things down. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717935/stack-overflow-during-swap/717984#717984

Comment: OOps, I should be more careful with my click, I didn't really mean to up vote that comment, but enjoy the point ;)

I re-read the Intel instruction manual for XCHG and only noticed a cache penalty on non-natural alignment access to the given operands. Maybe I'm missing something but you can inline XCHG in C/C++ for the most part, save 64bit MSVC, and I do think it satisfy's the question of not using the stack when swapping 2 variables, including the use of non-integer types.  

Also as other's had asked, this question does not really even seem to be language specific so Assembly is A-OK IMHO:)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

This will work for integers and float.

Comment: Read the link in this answer and then follow footnote 2 and read that. In short - it takes more memory and CPU cycles than the simple swap. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717935/stack-overflow-during-swap/717984#717984